# Loop up to x numbers, or less

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this code:

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4];

// This will work
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  console.log(arr[i]);
}

// And this will crash
for(let i=0;i<11;i++){
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

I need to loop through, and print out 12 values by default. But sometimes let's say the database returns an array with only 2 elements in it. Then the loop will crash on `arr[2]`.

On the other hand if the database returns an array with 100 elements, I want it to still only loop 12 times.

I could do a try catch inside of it, but that doesn't seem like a good practice.

```
for(let i=0;i<11;i++){
  try{
    console.log(arr[i]);
  }catch(e){

  }
}
```

It's all spaghetti now. I guess I could also check if the number is an undefined, like this:

```
// And this will crash
for(let i=0;i<11;i++){
  if(arr[i]!==undefined){
    console.log(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

But that still forces the loop to go 12 times. So is there a way of doing it, to make sure it will only run for as long as it's needed?

And there is also the break; way of doing things:

```
for(let i=0;i<11;i++){
  if(arr[i]!==undefined){
    console.log(arr[i]);
  } else{
    break;
    console.log('test'+i)
  }
}
```

But would there be a way to set the iterator limit like this?

```
for(let i=0; i<11 OR i<arr.length; i++)
```

Comment: "is there a way of doing it, to make sure it will only run for as long as it's needed?"...yes your very first snippet does that, the one where it stops on `arr.length`. What's wrong with that? I'm not sure I understand the difficulty

Comment: @ADyson If the array is over 11 elements I only want it to still print out 11 elements. Sorry I didn't specify this case

Comment: I see. `i < (arr.length < 11 ? arr.length : 11)` in that case I should think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of extend the check for either reaching the lenght of the array or `11`, you could take the `length` of the array or `11` as minimum value for the check of the index.

```
for (let i = 0, l = Math.min(array.length, 11); i < l; i++) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> But would there be a way to set the iterator limit like this?
>
> ```
> for(let i=0; i<11 OR i<arr.length; i++)
> ```

Yes, you can do exactly that, except you want to 'and' the conditions i.e. it has to be both less than 11 and less than the array length. The JavaScript boolean short-cut and operator is `&&`:

```
for(let i=0; i<11 && i<arr.length; i++)
```

Comment: Why would I need to use the and operator? I see this code works, but am just curious why it needs to be written this way

Comment: Because you want to check two conditions - that `i<11` and also still within the array bounds - and you need them both to be true (= and)? I'm not sure what you're asking sorry. You could equally well compare i to the array length first and then 11 afterwards if that's what you meant.

Comment: Ok now it makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary statement like so `i < (i<arr.length ? 11 : arr.length)`:

```js
function run_loop(arr) {
  for(let i=0; i < (i<arr.length ? 11 : arr.length); i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
  }
}

console.log("1st output");
run_loop([1, 2, 3, 4]); // Stops at 4 (doesn't try and print above the length of array)
console.log("2nd output:");
run_loop([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]); // Prints all values up to 11 (as specified in the for loop)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can compare value of i with array length before the print statement as shown below

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4];
// This will work
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
// And this will crash
for(let i=0;i<11;i++){
    //compare i and length
     if(i<arr.Length)
        console.log(arr[i]);
     else
       break;
}
```